# Group Policy to disable USB in windows 7 clients

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-7, group-policy

I want to disable the USB for Windows 7 clients through the Active Directory group policy ,is it possible ???and anyone can give me instructions please .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Group Policy Management Console (Windows 2008/Windows7 RSAT):

User or Computer policy

Administrative Templates > Removable Storage

You can either set both policies for "Removable Disks..." or "All Removable Storage classes: Deny all access"

If you want to ensure it is disable for local account access, it should be a computer policy.

[image]

Comment: My server is 2003 any other solutions

Comment: Run GPMC from a Windows 7 workstation with Remote Server Administration Tools.

Comment: Do you mean that when I install it I will be able to apply the policy from my windows 7 as I am login as domain administrator and any changes will applies in all users ?? .. can you explain more please.

Comment: Yes, you can edit the group policies from a Windows 7 computer with the Remote Server Administration Tools installed, and the policy will apply to all users/computers.  It doesn't matter what computer you run GPMC from.

Comment: Do I have to install CSE for new group policy preference in the windows 2003 server first????

Comment: No, that would only be if you had Windows XP clients, and only if this setting used Group Policy Preferences  (it doesn't).

Comment: From my test you need it, and its wrote in the KB, it give the extension, but does not give the gpmc extension to edit them. (thus the need for rsat on another computer).

Answer (score 1):

For usb stick;
- The CSE for new group policy preference must be installed on your server

- Install RSAT on a windows 7 computer
- From there you will be able to use a GPP to achieve your goal. Open GPMC, User configuration, policy, administrative template, system, removable storage media, enable/disable

For anything else, disregard my answer, as I think you need a third part software to achieve your goal

Comment: Where can I find the CSE and install it in the 2003 server to apply the windows 7 clients

Comment: @HusseinAlkahli There, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943729

Comment: So ether to install CSE in window server 2003 to apply the policy or to install RSAT In windows 7 and apply the police for all users form there ???  is it this way???

Comment: @HusseinAlkahli both needed! check my answer, all step told. :)